# How do I customize Jupyter Notebook autocomplete accept suggestion keyboard shortcut?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

When I type a '.' after an object name and press the TAB key I am able to see the suggested completions. To confirm and insert a suggested completion I have to use the arrow keys to select the completion I want and then press the ENTER key to confirm my selection. Is there a way to change this so that the TAB key confirms my selection?

Answer (score -4):

> Is there a way to change this so that the TAB key confirms my selection?

No there is no way to do that.

Comment: It would be better to explain *why* this is not possible. Otherwise it's just a random opinion. Someone might come up with an unexpected solution or workaround.

Comment: Can you provide some evidence to support this? I don't know which way to vote on this answer because I don't know if it's true or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome. SO is designed to work different than a forum. With no explanation, & no link to documentation, & no info to support your 1 word response, this reads more like an opinion, than an Answer. At best you could maybe post as a Comment to the OP, but without additional info, even that does not seem helpful. As Answers usually require "exact code necessary to solve the issue", it follows a "not possible" reply needs to be held to the same level of burden. Please `edit` to add additional info re: How you arrived at this conclusion. Alt, if you delete it before SO does, you might earn a badge.